# How to leave and join room again using PUN?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, photon

How do I properly exit a player from a room, and later join him again to the same room when he wants? This is not the same as rejoining mentioned here:
[How to Rejoin a player to a room using PUN Unity3D?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34991844/how-to-rejoin-a-player-to-a-room-using-pun-unity3d)
We will join that player as a new player. I know PhotonNetwork.Disconnect() and PhotonNetwork.LeaveRoom().

I am facing different problems with these:

1. PhotonNetwork.Disconnect(): After doing this, same room is not available for that player, and I get game doesn't exist error.
2. PhotonNetwork.LeaveRoomo(): Player can rejoin room, but there are many other issues, and I will have to rework all the code.

Also, I have set autoCleanupPlayerObjects to false, because it was destroying some necessary objects. Do I need to do any additional clean up? Can I make same room available after PhotonNetwork.Disconnect()?

Comment: the answer in the link is the basically the correct answer, you need to generate a "key" for each player once the game starts. Then, when a player leaves (you can get notified for it), save their state (like if the player has a position and amount of HP save those), then when a player connects with the key, you have to assume that's the same one, and send them that data. The joining player needs to recreate their objects based on that data.

Comment: what is the value of `RoomOptions.PlayerTtl` when you create rooms? How do you want to re enter rooms? Do you want to keep old state or join as a new unknown player?